# Bash command not working with ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, bash

The following command executes fine in bash:

Command:

```
bash -c "$(echo 'H4sIAArQ/mAAA1WMuw7CIBRAd77ihLJqtKuTg19hHIjetiQU0svl/1sn43weaeKJD4PnlI2R1w1bpOBA3kvF340ssX1Z1LmvUqyhsvWk8jl7nOQmP/2x9ZixSlXWqnLcYvlrw4VwJYxHOiW3AwCHgS2AAAAA' | base64 --decode | zcat)" - -a -b
```

Output:

```
Equal to or more than 2 arguments - -a -b
```

Wanted to know - how can I achieve this using Java's ProcessBuilder?

I tried the following:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(args);
```

where args are:

```
bash
-c
"$(echo 'H4sIAArQ/mAAA1WMuw7CIBRAd77ihLJqtKuTg19hHIjetiQU0svl/1sn43weaeKJD4PnlI2R1w1bpOBA3kvF340ssX1Z1LmvUqyhsvWk8jl7nOQmP/2x9ZixSlXWqnLcYvlrw4VwJYxHOiW3AwCHgS2AAAAA' | base64 --decode | zcat)"
-
-a
-b
```

But I keep on getting the following error:

```
-: if: command not found

Process finished with exit code 127
```

Can someone please point out the issue here?

Comment: I suspect you're taking code that was built to be evaluated by an _outer_ shell, and then using it in an environment where there's only one shell -- an inner one.

Comment: See https://replit.com/@CharlesDuffy2/SmartUniqueAnalysts#Main.java

Comment: By the way: Your compressed base64-string alone is longer (156 bytes) than the uncompressed program itself (124 bytes). Why not execute the uncompressed program directly to safe some resources and avoid the problems?

Comment: Socowi, the main problem is on a long script (6000 chars). The compression ratio remains 60% for that case. The above problem is just for representation.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you for the info and for posting a minimal example instead of the full script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command substitution results, in bash, don't go through all parsing steps. That means that compound commands like `if` aren't honored, command separators like `;` have no syntactic meaning, etc.

If you want to override that and force an additional parsing pass, you need to use `eval`. Thus:

```java
args = String[]{
  "bash",
  "-c",
  "eval \"$(echo 'H4sIAArQ/mAAA1WMuw7CIBRAd77ihLJqtKuTg19hHIjetiQU0svl/1sn43weaeKJD4PnlI2R1w1bpOBA3kvF340ssX1Z1LmvUqyhsvWk8jl7nOQmP/2x9ZixSlXWqnLcYvlrw4VwJYxHOiW3AwCHgS2AAAAA' | base64 --decode | zcat)\"",
  "-",
  "-a",
  "-b",
}
```

Why did this work when you ran it in a shell, instead of from a ProcessBuilder? *Because that shell you ran it in* would perform the command substitution in `"$(...)"`, and put the results of that substitution in the text it passed to the child shell; so the substitution was already done at parsing time.

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful explanation! Does it works the same way for the args as well? Let's say instead of `"-b"` I want to pass `"eval \"$(echo 'H4sIALLp/mAAA9NN4gIAmuzKeAMAAAA=' | base64 --decode | zcat)\""`?

Comment: Only the argument immediately after `-c` is parsed as code. All others keep their literal values. This is important from a security perspective -- otherwise, one could never write a bash script able to safely handle untrusted data.

Comment: Thanks, for the clarification.